# Supervised learning on symmetric vectors

Tags: supervised-learning, fourier-transform

I have a simple question: Let's say I'm applying the supervised learning method LVQ to a labeled data set in order to train a classifier. This data set contains feature vectors $x \in \mathbb{C}^N$ (These resulted from a Fourier transformation of discrete time domain signals, but that is not relevant). What is relevant is that the vectors $x$ have a completely conjugate symmetric part, i.e. these are vectors like this:
$ x =
\begin{pmatrix}
5+ 3i & 2 + 3i & 4 - 9i & 4 + 9i & 2 - 3i
\end{pmatrix}^T
$
and then of course for way higher dimensions. Observe that elements 2 and 3 are conjugate symmetric with 4 and 5.

Now my question: Given that basically one half of the vector contains the same information as the other half (not entirely the same, but conjugate symmetric), is it justified to just omit one half of the feature vectors for the training and classification? Would there be any reason to not omit one half of the spectrum? Would the performance of the classifier that resulted from the $N/2$ dimensional vectors be always the same/similar to the classifier that resulted from the full vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason I can think of to keep the whole FFT output would be if your original signal is ever complex, in which case the FFT would no longer be symmetric. There are no gains to be had by keeping the symmetric part because it's completely redundant. Because of this, it can't add any extra information about the class, which is what would increase classifier performance. Leaving it in will make downstream computations take longer because runtime scales with the dimensionality of the input (superlinearly for some algorithms).